# PugJS trying to use variable values on form attributes

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm currently trying to make a quiz using PugJS. I'm trying to group the answers that are in the body when the form is posted.

Currently when I post the following form I get this data:

[image: Form Image]

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

returns the following: `{"answer":["a","b","c","d","e","f"]}`

All of the data is in the same "answer" object.
In my PugJS file I do the following:

```
block contents
    form(action=url, method='POST')
        each question in config
            h1= question.question
            .row.mb-3
                - for (var x = 0; x < question.requiredAnswers; x++)
                    label.col-sm-2.col-form-label(for='answer') Antwoord #{x + 1}
                    .col-sm-10
                        input.form-control(type='text' name='answer' id='answer')
            hr
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit') Verzend de antwoorden
```

As you can see I keep using the same label(for='answer') and input(name='answer' id='answer')

I tried to use the variable x to change the objects to: label(for='answer #{x + 1}') and input(name='answer #{x + 1}' id='answer #{x + 1}')

The output I would like:
`{"answer1":["a"], "answer2":["b","c"], "answer3":["d","e","f"]}`

I also tried a escaping the variable using #{x + 1} but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will submit form parameters only as simple key-value pairs. If there are multiple keys with the same name, they will be submitted as they are, repeatedly. I think it is the Express `body-parser` middleware that converts keys with the same names into an array.

In Express, `req.body.someParameter` is a string value if `someParameter` occurs only once in your form. It is an array of strings if that parameter is received more than once.

```
doctype html
html
  body
    //- Test data:
    - const config = [ { requiredAnswers: 1}, { requiredAnswers: 2},{ requiredAnswers: 3}]
    form(method="post")
      each question,i in config
        p Q#{i+1}
          ul 
            - for (let x=0; x<question.requiredAnswers; x++)
              label(for="Q"+i+"A"+x) Antwoord #{x+1} 
              input(name="answer"+(i+1) id="Q"+i+"A"+x)
              br
      input(type="submit")
```

The above `label`s when clicked will set focus to each respective input box correctly. When submitted with the same values you used, the browser sends the following in the request payload:

```
answer1=a&answer2=b&answer2=c&answer3=d&answer3=e&answer3=f
```

and `req.body` at the server is:

```
{"answer1":"a","answer2":["b","c"],"answer3":["d","e","f"]}
```